# Possible bug in GNU make 4.3?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following line in the Makefile of a software I'm working with:

```
VERSION = $(subst $(space),.,$(wordlist 1,2,$(subst ., ,$(patsubst v%,%,$(shell cat VERSION)))))
```

Where `VERSION` is a file containing the exact version of the software (f.e `3.12.3`)

I'm not such an expert in Makefiles but this line should return the major version (without the `v` indicating TAG), in this case, 3.12. And it does, or, at least, it does it when you run it with GNU make <= 4.2

I've recently updated to make 4.3 (because I use a rolling release, Arch Linux) and then executing the same line in my makefile, I got `3 12.` instead of `3.12`

I've been reading Make changelog in order to check if there is any change in something related to the line in charge of retrieving the major version but I can't find where the problem is.

I've confirmed that the problem appears only with GNU make 4.3 (it works with make 4.2) and I'm wondering if there is a bug or I am missing something.

Maybe someone could help me.

Best regards

Comment: Can you provide a complete makefile?  How is `space` defined?

Comment: Oh. You're absolutely right, I didn't notice that I've defined space as:

```
space =
space +=
```

And the behaviour of `+=` on empty variables changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As G.M. mentioned, it all depends on how you've defined `space`, which you haven't shown us.

It worked for me using the "normal" way of defining `space`, with GNU make 4.3:

```
E =
space = $E $E
VERSION = $(subst $(space),.,$(wordlist 1,2,$(subst ., ,$(patsubst v%,%,$(shell cat VERSION)))))

$(info VERSION='$(VERSION)')
```

Then:

```
$ cat VERSION
v3.12.3

$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
 ...

$ make
VERSION='3.12'
```

Comment: Hello! You're right, I didn't noticed I had defined space using a `+=` into an empty var... and this have changed in this new version!

Answer (score 1):

As MadScientist and G.M mentioned, the problem was in the definition of `space`. I dind't noticed it was defined as

```
space =
space +=
```

and, according to Makefile 4.3 change log:

```
* WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
  Previously appending using '+=' to an empty variable would result in a value
  starting with a space.  Now the initial space is only added if the variable
  already contains some value.  Similarly, appending an empty string does not
  add a trailing space.
```

The expected behavior for `+=` to an empty variable has changed... so here is the problem!

Thank you very much!